# Is homeomorphic image into $\Bbb R^n$ always open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $U$ be open in $X$, $\phi:U\to\phi(U)$ be a homeomorphism ($\phi(U)\subseteq\Bbb R^n$). Then is $\phi(U)$ always open in $\Bbb R^n$? I think generally the answer is no, but I want a counterexample.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, but I didn't assume $X$ to be $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: I think the key point is: what topology are you using on $\phi(U)$ when you say "$\phi$ is a homeomorphism"?

Comment: Hint: Take X to be a singleton.

Comment: @trisct Standard topology induced by the $\ell^2$ metric. Does it matter? How?

Comment: What I wanted to say was, do you restrict the standard topology to $\phi(U)$ or not?

Comment: @trisct Oh, I see. I mean $\phi(U)$ is open with respect to $\Bbb R^n$ (i.e. no restrict). Otherwise any set is open w.r.t itself, it's a trivial consequence.

Comment: Well then the question is solved by assumption.

Comment: @trisct What? I don't understand

Comment: I wrote it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite you question as follows (the $\phi(U)$ notation is a bit confusing). And also assume wlog $X=U$.

> Let U be a topological space. $\phi:U\to A$ be a homeomorphism with $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then is $A$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Now by the definition of a homeomorphism, $A$ must be a topological space itself. Also from you comment you want the topology of $A$ to be induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $A$ must have the restricted topology.

So you can take any non-open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ be restricted to $A$ s.t. $A$ becomes a topological space. Then the inclusion
$$\phi:A\to A$$
is a homeomorphism but $A$ is non-open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

A shorter answer: you want to use the information that "$U\to A$ is a homeomorphism" to determine whether $A$ in open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But to use the word "homeomorphism" you must have a topology on $A$ beforehand, which has nothing to do with whether $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or not.

Comment: I see. So I think one line in wikipedia is wrong. See [this picture](https://imgur.com/9kCXxVd). The above red line is not exactly equivalent to the below redline right? Since "$f$ is an open map" can not guarantee that $f(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Well, it says $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ in injective and continuous. These are slightly different from your assumptions. So I don't think it is wrong. Perhaps you are confusing"injective continuous" with "homeomorphism"?

Comment: Got it. The key point is that $f:U\to\Bbb R^n$ being an open map is stronger then $f:U\to f(U)$ being an open map. They are different. The latter can not deduce that $f(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$, but the former can. (PS: My question 20 minutes was that I think the "equivalence" stated by wiki is problematic.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ that is not open and let it be equipped with subspace topology.

Let $U=X$ (so it is open in $X$).

Let $\phi:U\to U$ be the identity function on $U$ so that $\phi(U)=U$.

Then $\phi:U\to\phi(U)$ is a homeomorphism, but $\phi(U)=U=X$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.